# Bread Machine Loaf does not Dome

Tags: baking, bread

When baking a standard loaf in my Bread Machine, the top of the loaf seemed to collapse back in at some point, and instead of coming out with a nice rounded top, it looks like this:

[image: Flat top]

I've tried:

- More yeast
- Mixing in some self raising flour
- 2 tsp Lemon Juice
- Avoiding the timer settings
- Chopping butter into really small pieces

The standard setting is a four hour bake, the machine is windowless so I can't tell if a particular stage is at fault. The bread is still edible and tastes fine.

The recipe is the most basic from the [book](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.lakeland.co.uk/content/documents/Panasonic_Bread_Maker_Instructions_15352.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwih0Lzn8tPwAhUKsKQKHeFKDrIQFjABegQIAxAC&usg=AOvVaw2DxZlgI5g9cLn5SiOd6cYi) that came with the machine

> 3/4 tsp yeast
> 400g strong white flour
> 1 tsp sugar
> 15g butter
> 1 tsp salt
> 280ml water

Comment: Hi Jontia, thank you for coming back to share your findings! It seems to be a very common problem, and we already had a hugely active question with a different wording, but no good answers. I closed as a duplicate now, and merged the answers from this question into the other one, so people will be able to read your solution and profit from it. Sadly, the accepted mark doesn't move along when merging :( but I hope it will be made up by votes once people notice that there is a tried-and-working solution.